# Visual Studio - Fatal error C1057

Tags: c, embedded

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and getting trained in building WinCE 6.0 OS Image. I'm in the pin mux setup part. I have set a macro BSP_HC1, so the coding with that macro alone should work.  A part of the coding is,

```
#define PAD_ENTRY(x,y)      {PAD_ID(x),y,0},
#define SAFE_MODE            7
#define PAD_ID(x) (offsetof(OMAP_SYSC_PADCONFS_REGS,CONTROL_PADCONF_##x)/sizeof(UINT16))

// OMAP_SYSC_PADCONFS_REGS is a structure and CONTROL_PADCONF_GPMC_A1 (for eg.,) is an element in it.

#define INPUT_DISABLED          (0<<8)
#define MUXMODE(x)              ((x & 0x7)<<0)
typedef struct {
    UINT16 padID;
    unsigned int Cfg:15;    
    unsigned int inUse:1;
} PAD_INFO;



#ifdef BSP_HC1
#define GPMC_PADS \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))   \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))   
#else
#define GPMC_PADS \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A1       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A2       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))     \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A3       ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
#endif
```

It is called in main.c as,

```
static const PAD_INFO ebootPinMux[] = {
            DSS_PADS
            GPMC_PADS
        USBOTG_PADS
            END_OF_PAD_ARRAY
    };
```

While compiling I get the error: `fatal error C1057: unexpected end of file in macro expansion` and it points to GPMC_PADS. The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys083ye6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) explains the error that I might miss some parenthesis. But, that didn't help me solve this. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Does the error occur only when BSP_HC1 is defined?  What is the definition of SAFE_MODE, PAD_ENTRY, and PAD_INFO?

Comment: What are the definitions of `PAD_ID`, `BSP_HC1`, and `MUXMODE`?  Are the `GPMC_*` and `INPUT_DISABLED` macros just integers, or are they also complicated macros?

Comment: @kkrambo I have updated with the necessary macros.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I have updated with the necessary macros. BSP_HC1 is set to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I had missed a parenthesis! When I added it, the error got fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression you have given -

```
#define GPMC_PADS \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))   \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
```

The lines  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE)) and  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0)) are in same line.

Please check what is the implementation of PAD_ENTRY macro.
I strongly feel the problem is because of using the PAD_ENTRY macro twice in same line.
I feel it should be something like -

```
 #define GPMC_PADS \
 PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_A6   ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(SAFE_MODE))  + \
  PAD_ENTRY(GPMC_nCS2 ,INPUT_DISABLED | MUXMODE(0))
```

Means there should be some operation performed between the two PAD_ENTRY macro.

Comment: I'm actually developing it from an EVM BSP only. I'm only altering the code and its not a complete new one. It's already having the same format only.